# One part of Javascript/JQuery not working when adding my other Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am creating a Laravel/php forum for my class, and I am trying to get the "notifications" bar to work, but noticed that I have to sacrifice a part of my UI in order for it to appear(it types out and deletes strings put in the Javascript). I recognize the issue when I add the javascript that I believe is being used by a different JQuery than what I am using. It is this one specific part, all the rest of the javascript works.

Here is the code for the "typing" design:

HTML:

```
 <h1> <span class="typed"></span></h1> <br />
```

Javascript:

```
   $(function () {
    $(".typed").typed({
        strings: ["How hard is full stack development?", "Is Tupac still alive?",
            "What keeps you up at night?",
            "Ask really random stuff",
            "Do it, I dare you", "...", " （✿ ͡◕ ᴗ◕)つ━━✫・*。 "
        ],
        typeSpeed: 30,
        loop: true,
        backDelay: 2000,
    });
});
```

I tried using `$.noConflict()` and still no luck. Every time I uncomment this part:
 `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>`

the typing effect stops, but all the other JS works and the notification bar appears. If commented out, the notification bar goes away and the typing works again.

> Note: that JS redirects to app.js which is connected to a `.vue`. I have
>   messed around with the .vue including completely deleting it and the
>   typing effect still won't work when that reference to that JS in
>   included.

It's interesting because I have jQuery `($)` symbols used in other parts of my javascript that still work....

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you insert a new js code for dom when dom was loaded?

Comment: I do not believe I have messed with the Dom at all. I will look into it.

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to debug the problem? And how is this related to PHP or Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not including the js/app.js because that will launch Vue and apparently your page works just fine without it.
Find the javascript file that has the jQuery "typed" plugin and load that instead of loading js/app.js. Make sure to reference it AFTER the line where you load jQuery library.